# Unable to use Aurelia plugin

Tags: aurelia

I'm trying to move one of my custom elements into a plug-in so that I can re-use it across projects.

I had a look at the [skeleton plugin](https://github.com/aurelia/skeleton-plugin) and noticed that it has a `src/index.js` that returns a config with all custom elements defined as `globalResources`.

So I tried the same thing and I basically have:

**src/index.js**

```
export function configure (config) {
    config.globalResources([
        './google-map',
        './google-map-location-picker',
        './google-map-autocomplete'
    ]);
}
```

And then I have each one of my custom elements next to `index.js`, for example:

**google-map.js**

```
import {inject, bindable, bindingMode, inlineView} from 'aurelia-framework';

@inlineView(`
    <template>
        <div class="google-map"></div>
    </template>
`)
@inject(Element)
export class GoogleMapCustomElement {
    // All the Custom Element code here
}
```

I've also set up a basic npm script that runs babel on the code and sticks it in `dist/`:

```
"main": "dist/index.js",
"babel": {
  "sourceMap": true,
  "moduleIds": false,
  "comments": false,
  "compact": false,
  "code": true,
  "presets": [ "es2015-loose", "stage-1"],
  "plugins": [
    "syntax-flow",
    "transform-decorators-legacy",
    "transform-flow-strip-types"
  ]
},
"scripts": {
  "build": "babel src -d dist"
},
```

Tbh I'm not entirely sure this is all correct but I took some of it from the skeleton plugin and it seems to run fine.

Anyway, the problem I'm having is that after I install the plugin (`npm install --save-dev powerbuoy/AureliaGoogleMaps`), add it to my `aurelia.json` in `build.bundles[vendor-bundle.js].dependencies` and tell aurelia to use it in `main.js` (`.use.plugin('aurelia-google-maps')`) I get:

`GET http://localhost:9000/node_modules/aurelia-google-maps/dist/index/google-map.js` (404)

So my question is, where does it get the `dist/index/` part from?? I'm configuring my `globalResources` in `index.js` but nowhere does it say that I have an `index` *folder*.

What am I doing wrong?

Bonus question: What is the bare minimum required to transpile my ES6 plug-in code so that others can use it? Does my babel configuration look correct?

Comment: How did you add it to the aurelia.json file? just as "google-map", or did you specify a custom configuration? "google-map" : {....}?

Comment: I just added "aurelia-google-maps" but I've also tried `{"name": "aurelia-google-maps", "path": "../node_modules/aurelia-google-maps/dist/index"}`. Both produce the same result. I do believe "aurelia-google-maps" works fine (as my main property points to index.js)

Comment: I'm not sure about *why* it's failing, but the problem might have something to do with how Aurelia routes you to a page that might be defined by a file named `about.js`, but the URL says `localhost:9000/about`. In this case, if the algorithm making the `GET` request from `index.js` asks the server, "Where am I now?" and the server gives it `dist/index`, then `./google-map` of course directs to `dist/index/google-map`. So the question would be why is that algorithm being fed `dist/index` instead of `dist/index.js`. That's the only way it makes sense to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have absolutely no idea *why*, but in order to solve this problem I actually had to move my custom elements inside an `index/` folder.

So now I have this:

```
- index.js
- index/
    - custom-element-one.js
    - custom-element-two.js
```

And my `index.js` still looks like this:

```
export function configure (config) {
    config.globalResources([
        './custom-element-one',
        './custom-element-two'
    ]);
}
```

Where it gets `index/` from I guess I will never know, but this works at least.

I did need the babel plug-in Marton mentioned too, but that alone did not solve the mystery of the made up path.

Edit: To elaborate a bit further, if I name my main entry point something other than `index.js` the folder too needs that name. For example, if I were to rename `index.js` `main.js` I would need to put my `globalResources` inside a folder called `main/`.

Comment: That's odd. I'll look into, because I haven’t experienced such restrictions with my setup. I use `<plugin-name>.js` as main entry point, but it’s placed in `src/` folder. [link]( https://github.com/martonsagi/aurelia-editables/blob/master/src/aurelia-editables.ts).

Answer (score 1):

What about referencing your plugin within aurelia.json, like this:

```json
{
  "name": "aurelia-google-maps",
  "path": "../node_modules/aurelia-google-maps/dist",
  "main": "index"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Update:**

Edit: thanks for clarifying why you don't want to use the whole skeleton-plugin package.

Focusing on your original question: `aurelia-cli` uses RequireJS (AMD format) to load dependencies. Probably, your current output has a different format.

Add `transform-es2015-modules-amd` to babel.plugins to ensure AMD-style output, so it will be compatible with RequireJS and therefore with aurelia-cli.

```js
"babel": {
"sourceMap": true,
"moduleIds": false,
"comments": false,
"compact": false,
"code": true,
"presets": [ "es2015-loose", "stage-1"],
"plugins": [
        "syntax-flow",
        "transform-decorators-legacy",
        "transform-flow-strip-types",
        "transform-es2015-modules-amd"
    ]
}
```

**Original:**

There are several blog post about plugin creation, I started with this: http://patrickwalters.net/making-out-first-plugin/ .

Of course, there have been many changes since then, but it's a useful piece of information and most of it still applies.

I'd recommend using [plugin-skeleton](https://github.com/aurelia/skeleton-plugin) as project structure. It provides you with a working set of gulp, babel, multiple output formats out-of-the-box.
With this approach, your plugin's availability wouldn't be limited to JSPM or CLI only but everyone would have the possibility to install it regardless of their build systems.

Migration is fairly easy in your case:

- Download skeleton-plugin
- Copy your classes + `index.js` into `src/`
- `npm install`
- ...wait for it...
- `gulp build`
- check `dist/` folder
- most of your pain should now be gone :)

Here are some details based on my observations/experience.

**1. Main `index.js/plugin-name.js`:**

In general, a main/entry point is required, where the plugin's configure() method is placed. It serves as a starting point when using it within an Aurelia application. This file could have any name, usually it's `index.js` or `plugin-name.js` (e.g. aurelia-google-maps.js) to make it clear for other developers what should be included for bundling. Set that same entry point in package.json as well.

In addition to globalResources, you can implement a callback function to allow configuration overrides. That can be called in the application, which will use the plugin. [Example solution](https://github.com/martonsagi/aurelia-editables/blob/master/src/aurelia-editables.ts)

Plugin's `index.js`

```js
export * from './some-element';

export function configure(config, callback) {
    // default apiKey
    let pluginConfig = Container.instance.get(CustomConfigClass);
    pluginConfig.apiKey = '01010101';

    // here comes an override
    if (callback) {
        callback(pluginConfig);
    }

    ...

    config.globalResources(
        './some-element'
    );  
}
```

Your app's `main.js`

```js
export function configure(aurelia) {
  aurelia.use
    .standardConfiguration()
    .developmentLogging()
    .plugin('aurelia-google-maps', (pluginConfig) => {
        // custom apiKey
        pluginConfig.apiKey = '12345678';
    });

  aurelia.start().then(a => a.setRoot());
}
```

**2. HTML and CSS resources:**

- If you have html only custom elements, you can make them available using `globalResources`.
- Custom css styling is going to require a bit of additional configuration in bundling configuration (see below).

**3. Using the plugin with aurelia-cli: [Documentation](http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/article/aurelia/framework/latest/the-aurelia-cli/6)**

> One of the first new features you'll see soon is a command to help you with 3rd party module configuration. The command will inspect a previously npm-installed package, and make a configuration recommendation to you, automating the process if you desire.

While we are looking forward to that above moment, let's edit `aurelia.json`:

- Configure plugin dependencies. If there are any external libraries (e.g. Bootstrap), then those should be included before your plugin.
- Include your plugin:

```js
...
{
    "name": "plugin-name",
    "path": "../node_modules/plugin-name/dist/amd",
    "main": "plugin-name",
    "resources": ["**/*.html", "**/*.css"]  // if there is any
},
...
```

Now, your plugin is ready to include it in `main.js` as showed in **Section 1.**.

I hope you didn't get sick of reading the word 'plugin' so many (21!) times. :D

Comment: Thanks for this very thorough answer, however, it doesn't really answer my question :/ There's a reason I'm not using the skeleton plugin (it's super bloated), and all I'd really like to know is why Aurelia thinks my files are inside an index folder.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. You're right, I've focused so much on details that I've missed the original question in the end! :) Updated my answer.

Comment: Cheers :) I'm giving you the bounty now even though I'm unable to test this atm. I'll get back to you if it doesn't work out.

Comment: Wow, thanks! :) Of course, just let me know if there's any problem left and we'll figure it out.

Comment: *sadface* I made the change (added `transform-es2015-modules-amd` to the list of plugins) and while the output in dist/ changed a lot, I still get the same weird `index/aurelia-google-maps` 404 :/ Here's the repo if it helps; https://github.com/powerbuoy/AureliaGoogleMaps

Comment: Instead of `./google-map` I've also tried just `google-map` inside my `index.js`'s `config.globalResources` call, this just makes Aurelia look inside `src/google-map` instead of inside `node_modules/aurelia-google-maps/`...

Comment: Ok this is seriously annoying, but I'm actually able to solve the problem by moving my custom elements inside an `index/` folder. It feels so wrong, and I don't know _why_ it works (why `./file.js` inside `index.js` points to `index/file.js` I will never know) but it works. I did need the plug-in you mentioned too though.