# Unable to access VM properties from @inlineView

Tags: aurelia

I've created a simple custom element in Aurelia that uses an `@inlineView()` (because the view is tiny) but when I try to access one of my VM's properties from my inline view I just get "property is not defined";

```
import {inlineView} from 'aurelia-framework';

@inlineView(`<template><h1>${title}</h1></template>`)
export class MyCustomElement {
    constructor () {
        this.title = 'Hello, World!';
    }
}
```

This happens with `@bindable` as well;

```
export class MyCustomElement {
    @bindable title = 'Hello, World!';

    constructor () {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When the `<template><h1>${title}</h1></template>` is being interpreted, the interpreter tries to interpolate the `title` variable which does not exist yet. Try this:

```
@inlineView(`<template><h1 innerHTML.bind="title"></h1></template>`)
```

Or even easier:

```
@inlineView('<template><h1>${title}</h1></template>') // without accents
```

Comment: I see! I didn't know that's how it works (this is my first ES6 project). The only thing slightly annoying with regular quotes is that the whole template needs to be on one line. I guess if it needs to be more than that it belongs in its own `html` file anyway so.

Comment: Btw, you seem to know this stuff well. Do you have any idea how to solve [this other Aurelia related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39873585/unable-to-use-aurelia-plugin)?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is you are using a template literal in your inlineView decorator which is causing Javascript to evaluate ${title} before it gets passed to the inlineView decorator function. At that point, title does not exist. You need to pass a regular string in this instance using regular quotes (' or ") around the template string like so:

```
@inlineView("<template><h1>${title}</h1></template>")
```